# logcat shows a blank window for anything related to my app, but spams an irrelevant error messages for android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat, android-debug

Exactly what the title says.

How do I fix this? Logcat is not evil. It has worked for me in the past, but rarely this happens where it will just NOT show me my error messages. Idk why. I have debug mode enabled, and my package is selected as the filter, and nothing shows up. If I unselect my package as the filter, I get this horrible spam:

```
    07-02 20:45:41.058     284-8521/? E/Sensors﹕ createEventQueue: connection is NULL. SensorService died.
07-02 20:45:41.068     284-8521/? E/Sensors﹕ createEventQueue: connection is NULL. SensorService died.
07-02 20:45:41.068     284-8521/? E/Sensors﹕ createEventQueue: connection is NULL. SensorService died.
07-02 20:45:41.068     284-8521/? E/Sensors﹕ createEventQueue: connection is NULL. SensorService died.
07-02 20:45:41.068     284-8521/? E/Sensors﹕ createEventQueue: connection is NULL. SensorService died.
07-02 20:45:41.068     284-8521/? E/Sensors﹕ createEventQueue: connection is NULL. SensorService died.
```

I have a feeling that the spam may be pushing anything out of the console, which is a horrible thing to allow on logcats part.

Also, yes, I have restarted android studio multiple times...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reboot your phone, which works for me, I'm on a Samsung Note 3.